# React Native: optimizing flatlist render item with useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to figure out as many ways as possible to optimize flatlist since my flatlist component complains my flat list items takes too long to render (I am already using removeClippedSubviews, windowSize, maxToRenderPerBatch, React.memo etc.).

Is it good idea to wrap render function with useCallback?

For example, lets say I have function component originally in form:

```
const FlatListItem = ({ color1, color2, color3, color4 }) => {
  function renderViewWithColorLogic(color) {
    // do some computationally heavy process
    // ...

    return <View>{/* some components */}</View>;
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {renderViewWithColorLogic(color1)}
      {renderViewWithColorLogic(color2)}
      {renderViewWithColorLogic(color3)}
      {renderViewWithColorLogic(color4)}
    </View>
  );
};
```

If i wrap the render function with useCallback as:

```
const FlatListItem = ({ color1, color2, color3, color4 }) => {
  function _renderViewWithColorLogic(color) {
    // do some computationally heavy process
    // ...

    return <View>{/* some components */}</View>;
  }
  const renderViewWithColorLogic1 = useCallback(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color1), [color1])
  const renderViewWithColorLogic2 = useCallback(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color2), [color2])
  const renderViewWithColorLogic3 = useCallback(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color3), [color3])
  const renderViewWithColorLogic4 = useCallback(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color4), [color4])

  return (
    <View>
      {renderViewWithColorLogic1()}
      {renderViewWithColorLogic2()}
      {renderViewWithColorLogic3()}
      {renderViewWithColorLogic4()}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Will it enhance the performance of the flatlist?
Any other suggestion to optimize flatlist will be appreciated as well.

---

So far as Andres says, I think better way to implement flatlist item component with some computation is as follow:

```
const FlatListItem = ({ color1, color2, color3, color4 }) => (
  const viewWithColorLogic1 = useMemo(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color1), [color1]);
  const viewWithColorLogic2 = useMemo(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color2), [color2]);
  const viewWithColorLogic3 = useMemo(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color3), [color3]);
  const viewWithColorLogic4 = useMemo(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color4), [color4]);

  return (
    <View>
      {viewWithColorLogic1}
      {viewWithColorLogic2}
      {viewWithColorLogic3}
      {viewWithColorLogic4}
    </View>
  );
);

function renderViewWithColorLogic(color) {
    // do some computationally heavy process
    // ...

    return <View>{/* some components */}</View>;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useCallback()` hook just keeps the same ref for callback when you need to pass it as a prop into some memoized/pure component. If you just call function on each render - there is no point to wrap it with `useCallback()`.

If this function not depends on other props then colors, you can just extract it from your component and avoid of function creation on each render:

```js
const FlatListItem = ({ color1, color2, color3, color4 }) => (
    <View>
      {renderViewWithColorLogic(color1)}
      {renderViewWithColorLogic(color2)}
      {renderViewWithColorLogic(color3)}
      {renderViewWithColorLogic(color4)}
    </View>
);

function renderViewWithColorLogic(color) {
    // do some computationally heavy process
    // ...

    return <View>{/* some components */}</View>;
}
```

If you have some heavy computation in your function, it's probably better to use `useMemo()` to memoize result:

```js
const FlatListItem = ({ color1, color2, color3, color4 }) => {
  const viewWithColorLogic1 = useMemo(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color1), [color1]);
  const viewWithColorLogic2 = useMemo(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color2), [color2]);
  const viewWithColorLogic3 = useMemo(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color3), [color3]);
  const viewWithColorLogic4 = useMemo(()=>_renderViewWithColorLogic(color4), [color4]);

  return (
    <View>
      {viewWithColorLogic1}
      {viewWithColorLogic2}
      {viewWithColorLogic3}
      {viewWithColorLogic4}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Since you have static number of colors, you can create views in a loop and disable eslint rule `react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` here: `const views = [ color1, color2, color3, color4 ].map( color => useMemo(renderViewWithColorLogic(color), [color]) ); return (<View>{ views }</View>)`;

Comment: I see. I was a bit confused by difference between useMemo and UseCallback. I will try extracting the render function outside of the component and try the useMemo. Thank you for the support. I will open up this issue a bit more to get more feed back.