# React Native Button onPress performance

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-native

So I have these buttons that do 2 things like checkbox button,
Change color , toggle between green and black
Stating checked as true or false

My issue is : button that I pressed has mild delay before It changes color, bad performance overall for my app , already tried this in my Redmi 5 Redmi note 9 and Galaxy a8, they all have mild delay with different delay duration Redmi 5 has longest delay like almost 1 sec.
My question is : Is there any faster / better performance code for these buttons ? Is this wrong way to do it ?

Here is my code :
first I state the initial value

```
const [booleanMonth,setMonth]=useState([
{key:0,value:'January',title:'Jan',color:'black',checked:false},
{key:1,value:'February',title:'Feb',color:'black',checked:false},
{key:2,value:'March',title:'Mar',color:'black',checked:false},
{key:3,value:'April',title:'Apr',color:'black',checked:false},
{key:4,value:'May',title:'May',color:'black',checked:false},
{key:5,value:'June',title:'Jun',color:'black',checked:false},
{key:6,value:'July',title:'Jul',color:'black',checked:false},
{key:7,value:'August',title:'Aug',color:'black',checked:false},
{key:8,value:'September',title:'Sep',color:'black',checked:true},
{key:9,value:'October',title:'Oct',color:'black',checked:false},
{key:10,value:'November',title:'Nov',color:'black',checked:false},
{key:11,value:'December',title:'Dec',color:'black',checked:false}
])
```

second, I create the buttons

```
  const createButtonMonth = () =>{
    return (<View style={styles.containerForButtons2}>
            {
              booleanMonth.map((item,key) => 
                <View key={item.key} style={styles.buttonFilter3}>
                <Button style={styles.buttonFilter3}
                title={item.title} 
                value={booleanMonth[item.key].checked} 
                color={booleanMonth[item.key].checked==true ? 'green':'black'}
                onPress={()=>onPressMonthFilter(booleanMonth[item.key].key,booleanMonth[item.key].checked)}
                /></View>)
            }
            </View>)
    }
```

third I make function to change button color green to back and checked status from false to true vice versa

```
 const onPressMonthFilter = (keyMonth,statusMonth) =>{    
    let newArr = [...booleanMonth]
    if(newArr[keyMonth].checked==false){
      newArr[keyMonth].checked=true
    }else{
      newArr[keyMonth].checked=false
    }
    
    setMonth(newArr)

  }
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try the testing with release mode? If it is debug mode, performance is generally bad and you don't have to mind.

Comment: YES ! even i tried as apk

Comment: Be careful, there is couple way to make apks.
Did you follow this https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.html and then tried --variant=release?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to optimize the code itself, try useMemo()
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Or React.memo() https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Basically, these check inputs like useEffect and determine if the part of function needs to rerender the component.

I am assuming `setMonth(newArr)` causes entire buttons to rerender, meaning as a number of elements in the booleanMonth increases, worse the performance gets.

Also, try to get release version of the apk/ipa. Usually, debug mode is really slow.
Follow this https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.html and get --variabe=release.

Comment: thanks for the info , still doesn't get how to make it better tho, but ill try again tomorow
arigatou

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Also this might help. I tried to optimize some react native behavior before. And this was the answers I got last year https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930232/react-native-optimizing-flatlist-render-item-with-usecallback

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hikaru Watanabe for the solution,
here is the answer to my question.

So I just realized what slows me down is actually another
2 Arrays UseState (I dont include those in question since I thought it's not relatable);
UseState for Year
UseState for Branch

They all looping to create buttons just like I loop months button
and its all re - render hence, looping again everytime i press Month button and vice versa

so this is the solution :

```
  const createButtonMonth = useMemo(() =>{
    console.log('createButtonMonth')
    return (<View style={styles.containerForButtons2}>
            {
              booleanMonth.map((item,key) => 
                <View key={item.key} style={styles.buttonFilter3}>
                <Button style={styles.buttonFilter3}
                title={item.title} 
                value={booleanMonth[item.key].checked} 
                onCheckColor='red'
                color={booleanMonth[item.key].checked==true ? 'green':'black'}
                onPress={()=>onPressMonthFilter(booleanMonth[item.key].key,booleanMonth[item.key].checked)}
                /></View>)
            }
            </View>)
  },[booleanMonth])
```

althou it's way faster but it still slows since

```
 const onPressMonthFilter = (keyMonth,statusMonth) =>{    
    let newArr = [...booleanMonth]
    if(newArr[keyMonth].checked==false){
      newArr[keyMonth].checked=true
    }else{
      newArr[keyMonth].checked=false
    }
    
    setMonth(newArr)

  }
```

code above still loops everytime and still dont have solution for this